# Achieving tab-like navigation with spaces indentation

Tags: python, pycharm, indentation

I am collaborating on a Python project, using PyCharm. It is space indented and I have been using only tab indentation so far. However, after switching to space indentation I am no longer able to navigate efficiently. To navigate one indentation level back, I need to press left arrow four times now, which I find very frustrating. Note that I mean navigation through an indentation level at a time (4 spaces) and not going to the beginning of the line.

My questions are:

- Can I set up navigation with space indented file in PyCharm to behave like it does with tabs (single arrow tap for one indentation level, single backspace for one indent deleted)?
- If not, is there a shortcut or a way to set up one to navigate to a previous indentation level?
- Are you aware of any other python IDEs that can handle space indentation in the way described?

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

For changing the key of indention I think you could change that from File -> Setting -> Keymap then search for indent selection.

Comment: Indent selection shortcut is for making an indentation (Tab by default). What I am interested in is navigating between indentation levels (the usual way of navigation with tab indentation).

Answer (score 0):

To toggle between tabs and spaces:

> On the main menu, choose **Edit | Convert Indents** , and then choose **To Spaces** or **To Tabs** respectively.

When you clone, download or in any other way start working on a project, you can convert *spaces* to *tabs* and stick with yours navigation. When you are done, you can convert *tabs* back to *spaces* so you don't break yours team coding habits.